# tkinter - how to update button text before command function ends?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have read numerous questions here but none actually answered my puzzle:

```
openFolderBtnGenerate = Button(top, text="Generate", command=lambda: compute(csv_file_name, lan, lon, alt))

openFolderBtnGenerate.grid(row=5, column=1)

def compute(csv_file_name, lat_0, lon_0, alt_0):
   global openFolderBtnGenerate
   openFolderBtnGenerate['text'] = "Please wait..."
   # here mathematical computation code that takes 10 seconds to accomplish
   ...
   # end
```

I intended the button text to change **before** the computation starts so users understand it might take some time to accomplish.
What really happens is that the button text is changed only after the computation ends.

How can I make the button text change right after the button is clicked, without having to wait these long 10 seconds?

Comment: You can probably use the universal widget method [`update_idletasks()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html). If that doesn't work try just `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

See line "root.update_idletasks()":

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def start_task():
    btn_text.set("Please wait for task to finish...")
    btn.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    btn_text.set("Press to start a task")
    

btn_text = tk.StringVar()
btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=btn_text, command=start_task)
btn_text.set("Press to start a task")

btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And another sample, without time.sleep() (for UI not to freeze):

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def update_text():
    btn_text.set("Press to start a task")

def start_task():
    btn_text.set("Please wait for task to finish...")
    btn.update_idletasks()
    root.after(2000, update_text)

btn_text = tk.StringVar()
btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=btn_text, command=start_task)
btn_text.set("Press to start a task")

btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks! that actually did almost exactly what I intended.
I changed its state to be "disabled" until the task is over. now it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want to do is just to change text as you press the button then run the function, so a small thing you can do is make another function **CODE :**

```
Def function2()
    global openFolderBtnGenerate
    openFolderBtnGenerate['text'] = "Please wait..."
    compute(csv_file_name, lan, lon, alt)

openFolderBtnGenerate = Button(top, text="Generate", command=function2)

openFolderBtnGenerate.grid(row=5, column=1)

def compute(csv_file_name, lat_0, lon_0, alt_0):
   # here mathematical computation code that takes 10 seconds to accomplish
   ...
   # end
```

It works for me and will surely work for you too.